# How to add fragment into fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

i want to implement my_fragment1 into tab1 fragment how can i combine the fragment into fragment.

**Tab1**

```
 public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    list_fragment fm = (list_fragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.My_Container_1_ID);
}
```

**Tab1.xml**

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_1_ID"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button">
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: not add fragment into fragment use activity and replace your fragmnet

Comment: We can use multiple fragment in Activity

Comment: because in my case i use nid to use swipe tab, so, cant implement in activity

Comment: You are going to implement swipe functionality right?

Comment: ya, i am going to use swipe tab

Comment: You can refer this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want add another fragment to Tab1 fragment, you can use `getChildFragmentManager()` to add. In  `onActivityCreated` of Tab1 fragment,
you can add another fragment

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.My_Container_1_ID, "your fragment here")
                .commit();
    }
```

And don't write codes after `return  ....`.